# Interfaces with hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, gilead

i am wondering how i would be able to annotate an interface

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDER_TABLE")
public class Folder implements Serializable, Hierarchy {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "folder_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   private int fId;

   @Column(name = "folder_name")
   private String folderName;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "FOLDER_JOIN_FILE_INFORMATION_TABLE", joinColumns = 
{ @JoinColumn(name = "folder_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = 
{ @JoinColumn(name = "file_information_id") })
    private List< Hierarchy > fileInformation = new ArrayList< Hierarchy >();
}
```

above and below are 2 classes that implement an interface called Hierarchy, the folder class has a list of Hierarchyies being a folder or a fileinformation class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE_INFORMATION_TABLE")
public class FileInformation implements Serializable, Hierarchy {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "file_information_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private int ieId;
  @Column (name = "location")
  private String location;
}
```

I have searched the web for someway to annotate or a workaround but I cannot map the interface which is simply this

```
public interface Hierarchy {

}
```

I get a mapping exception on the List of hierarchies with a folder but I don't know how to 
map the class correctly.

Answer (score 11):

You can map interfaces in Hibernate, as part of inheritance hierarchies. This is quite surely possible with XML mapping, as it is described in [Chapter 9 of the Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html), among others.

Annotation based mapping is a different story though. I am not so familiar with it, but [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/) includes examples for this too. Adapted to your case, it would look like

```
@MappedSuperclass
public interface Hierarchy {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOLDER_TABLE")
public class Folder implements Serializable, Hierarchy { ... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE_INFORMATION_TABLE")
public class FileInformation implements Serializable, Hierarchy { ... }
```

This mapping would use a table per concrete class with implicit polymorphism.

However, other sources suggest that annotation support for interfaces may not be working / stable yet:

- there is a related [open bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4413) on using the `@Entity` annotation with interfaces, which also includes some patches,
- here is a [related (fairly old) thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2238824), describing a workaround using XML mapping.

So you may need to experiment, including changing your inheritance mapping strategy, maybe turning the interface into an abstract class (if it's possible - since a class can only extend a single base class)...

Comment: rite so , i realised as my folders will be able to have many sub folders and fileInformations i would need to use the composite pattern to help. i found this online http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/blog/archives/57

it shows how to map composite pattern using annotations

Comment: also all i basically want is to persist a hierarchy(tree) structure. i f someone knows a tutorial out there, im finding it quite hard to understand the hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A little Googling turned up...

> You can use interfaces internally but
>   **you can't map interfaces in hibernate**,
>   you have to map classes, regardless of
>   whether you are using xml mapping or
>   annotation mapping. hibernate is
>   handling lifecycle of your persistent
>   objects so it needs to know what class
>   to instantiate so you need to provide
>   this information to it... I am not
>   even sure how what you suggesting
>   would even look like? how would you
>   provide implementation for given
>   interface to hibernate at runtime to
>   instantiate?

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=67420

So it looks like you are out of luck.

Comment: @Kris You should have read further... the same thread includes a post in the end where the OP tells he managed to resolve the issue.

Comment: The document http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/pdf/hibernate_reference.pdf on its page 30 endorses with what you said.