# Hibernate mapping Interface with multiple targetEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, interface, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to develop an application with Hibernate and javax.persistence Annotations. I have some troubles in mapping an interface.

I have mapped my interface as @MappedSuperclass and I have already tried to use the attribute targetEntity in my ManyToOne Annotation that referred to the interface and it worked.
The problem is that I would more than one class to act as targetEntity. In particular I'd like that every class that implements my interface, could be recognized as a target entity.

Does anybody knows if it's possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this

> In particular I'd like that every class that implements my interface,
> could be recognized as a target entity.

is not possible. Only classes which are annotated with `@Entity` or which are mapped in an other way (for example with a mapping file) can be persisted.

Also, the [Hibernate documentation says](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168):

> #### Note
>
> Annotating interfaces is currently not supported.

See the rather old question [Interfaces with hibernate annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2586583/1374678) for additional information.

Comment: I think you're right. Infact, I have annotated each class that implements the interface with @Entity and it works whene I choose only one of them to be the target entity. Hope to see interface support in the next version of Hibernate!